# MySql IF daylight saving

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have table with dates saved in UTC +00:00. Pre-mysql call PHP sets timezone offset with or without daylight saving:

```
date_default_timezone_set($tzone); 
$tzoffset = date("P");
```

Mysql call adds hours depending of users timezone:

```
CONVERT_TZ(d.dateTime,'+00:00', '".$tzoffset."') AS dateTime,
```

Yesterdays 09:00 before daylight saving, today is displayed as 10:00. How to retrieve date from before daylight saving at it's original time? Some sort of IF logic in Mysql call as I use in PHP?:

```
$date = new DateTime( $row[ 'dateTime' ] );

    $tzDaylightSaving = $date->format("I"); //checking if daylight saving for specific time is active
            if ($tzDaylightSaving == 1)
            {
            $date->add(new DateInterval('PT1H')); //if daylight saving is active, add one hour
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a MySQL problem.  In the call to `CONVERT_TZ`, as far as MySQL sees it, the client SQL is specifying a fixed offset from UTC.  From the code, it looks like that that offset is derived from current date and time, independent of whether the datetime value stored in `dateTime` column.

MySQL is perfectly capable of handling timezone that observe daylight saving time. We could pass in the actual time_zone value (assuming the mysql.time_zone% tables are populated) e.g. `PST8PDT`, or `America/Chicago`

```
  CONVERT_TZ( t.datetime_utc ,'+00:00','PST8PDT')
  CONVERT_TZ( t.datetime_utc ,'+00:00','America/Chicago')
```

Or, we could just return the UTC value from MySQL, and do the conversion in the code.

If we are committed to sending a fixed offset in the SQL text, and returning a datetime value offset from UTC, then in the code, we need to account for that.

As the code stands, the value being returned by MySQL is *not* in time_zone `$tzone`. It's a value with a wonky fixed offset from UTC.  When we go to instantiate that value as a PHP DateTime, the code is using the wrong time_zone. We would need to interpret that MYSQL value as being a fixed offset from UTC.

At the point in the code it's doing the `if` check, it's too late. The `$date` value is wrong because it's being interpreted as if its in the default time zone `$tzone`... and it's not. The value from MySQL has been shifted a fixed number of hours.

---